# How can I get latitude and location from a customer by making him to place a marker in google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got api for android. But In website how can I get location of a person by making him to place a marker by providing him a google map?

Is there any standard way to use the same? I need to get these latitude and longitude and pass to the backend.. How can I achieve the same? I am doing it the first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use google map's `click` event to get latitude and longitutde as follows:

```js
 function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    zoom: 8,
    center: uluru,
    clickableIcons: true,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

    if (map.getClickableIcons()) {
      var Latitude = e.latLng.lat();
      var Longitude = e.latLng.lng();
      // add your new marker with this info.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: Latitude,
          lng: Longitude
        },
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
      });
      map.clickableIcons = false;
      // get latitude and longitude after dragging:
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', 
      function(marker){
           var latLng = marker.latLng; 
           currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
           currentLongitude = latLng.lng();

 }); 


    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCu8vqg35dD4fNfxlI8ICoycehbL0F6bis&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

> Learn more about [map's dom-listners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener)

Comment: sir, i need to provide a google map to the user and make him to place a marker according to his need

Comment: I have added a code snippet, you can check the implementation. it is working fine.

Comment: sir, i need to add only one marker per user.. in this case on clicking many markers are coming. how can i limit to one

Comment: also, is it possible to print that latitude and longitude selected

Comment: yes u can print desired lat long they are accessible by `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

Comment: add `clickableIcons: false` to map's meta info after first click, to disable multiple clicks.

Comment: can you update the code. is there possible to drag the marker?